# Populate image using advance custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to populate image in **wordpress** archive page side bar. This will be linked to any URL.

How can I do so that I can write URL and image link. Then **ACF (Advance custom field)** populates the clickable image in my **archive** page sidebar.

I am getting confused over this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying yo display an image to archive page, you should create an options page first. The archive page doesn't have an ID, so the field value should be added as option. You can read more about options page [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/).

Then you should add the field to options page.
After that when the image is saved you should [get the value from option page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/) and display it to your archive page.